# Fill dropdown list with json and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to fill drop-down list via ajax call my code is working fine until I send back the result (list of objects) in Json format.

This is my entity model that I am trying to fill:

```
 public partial class stkInvoicesTypesTbl
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public stkInvoicesTypesTbl()
    {
        this.stkInvoicesTbls = new HashSet<stkInvoicesTbl>();
    }

    public int invTypesTableId { get; set; }
    public string invTypeDesc { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<stkInvoicesTbl> stkInvoicesTbls { get; set; } //this property throw Exception and i think here is my problem
}
```

Here is my ajax call and script code

```
var InvType = []

// fetch invoice type from database
function LoadInvoiceType(element)
{   
    if (InvType.length == 0) {
        //ajax function to fetch data
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/InvoiceItm/getInvoiceType',

            success: function (data) {
                InvType = data;

                renderInvoiceType(element);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                InvType = data;
            }
        })
    }
    else {
        //render invoice type to elements
        renderInvoiceType(element);
    }
}

function renderInvoiceType(element)
{
    var $ele = $(element);
    $ele.empty();

    $.each(InvType, function (i, val) {
        $ele.append($('<option/>').val(val.invTypesTableId).text(val.invTypeDesc));
    })
}
```

My action controller:

```
public JsonResult getInvoiceType()
{
        List<stkInvoicesTypesTbl> InvoiceTypes = new List<stkInvoicesTypesTbl>();

        using (iraqEntities dc = new iraqEntities())
        {
            InvoiceTypes = dc.stkInvoicesTypesTbls.OrderBy(a => a.invTypeDesc).ToList();
        }

        return new JsonResult { Data = InvoiceTypes, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

My view :

```
<td><label for="input-text" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Invoice Type</label> </td>
            <td>
                <select type="text" id="InvoiceType" class="col-sm-3 form-control" onchange="LoadInvoiceType(this)"></select>

            </td>
```

My list filled correctly in controller but when i send it back in json format (return JsonResult ...)it's return error .

And here is some screenshots for my debugging could be helpful:

[return my data from database and fill my list in controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ip8x.png)

[this property is generated automatically from Entity Framework (foreign key relation) and it's throwing an exception so I think my problem lies here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0xx5.png)

So, anyone can help me in my problem it will be appreciated

Comment: hi I think you need to use include in you query .

Comment: yes it's work now thank you dear.

Comment: welcome I hope I put it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to Include property stkInvoicesTbls in your query

```
    using (iraqEntities dc = new iraqEntities())
    {
        InvoiceTypes = dc.stkInvoicesTypesTbls
                         .Include("stkInvoicesTbls")
                         .OrderBy(a => a.invTypeDesc)
                         .ToList();
    }
```

Comment: I try it and it's give me syntax error :cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string'  because it's not delegate type. @Ahmed Ragheb